# Optionally using Cloud Firestore in an app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that uses SQLite to store the users' data (stats and such). The app doesn't require users to sign up or log in. I would like to add the capability for cloud syncing of data to the app, so Cloud Firestore sounds like a great fit. However I don't want to force users to sign up or log in if they don't want to use cloud syncing features.

Is there some clever way to use Firestore locally without having to log in users? That way I could convert the SQLite data to non-relational format once and have one place where the data is stored. Otherwise I'd have to maintain and update two databases - one for users who don't want to sign up/log in, and another for those that do.

Comment: How would you get cloud syncing to work on another device? You need a unique identifier to know which record(s) to pull out for the user!

Comment: I'd need that for users who want to use that feature. But I also have users who don't want to sync or sign up to anything and I'd like both kinds of users to use the app and ideally have only one database instead of two.

Comment: I'd suggest if they're not using cloud features, don't use firestore for them. You're charged for every read write and delete to firestore, so it'd be better for you to actually maintain two I reckon. Plus, no network calls means it'll be quicker for those not using the cloud.

Comment: Agreed-it's a cloud store. If your data layer is abstracted you could use a native solution that looks roughly like cloud store-you don't necessarily need to use sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore doesn't require users to sign in. You can easily use Firestore without having the users sign in. I do this all the time, since data in my apps is often simply shared between all users without any sense of ownership.

However: finding a user's data in a cloud-hosted database requires that you're able to identify the user. If you already have a way to identify them, then you can continue to use that identification with Firestore.

If you don't currently have a way to identify users, I recommend looking at [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). This is a completely transparent, non-interactive way to add a user identification token.